How to trigger another action when tapping a ShareLink
Currently using SwiftUI built in ShareLink functionality.
I need to trigger a different action at the same time that ShareLink is pressed.
This ShareLink is nested within a SwiftUI Menu.
How would I accomplish this?
Here is an example of my code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu("options") {
                Button {
                    print("button 1 is pressed")
                } label: {
                    Text("Test Menu Button")
                }
            
                shareLinkButton
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("ShareLink triggered!")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    var shareLinkButton: some View {
        ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!) {
            Label {
                Text("hello")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("HELLO")
                    }
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("ShareLink triggered!")
        }
    }
}

It is just a basic Menu with two buttons in them.
None of the onTapGestures get triggered at any point.
I've also tried to wrap ShareLink within a button, like this:
        Button {
            ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!) {
                Label {
                    Text("hello")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("HELLO")
                        }
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                }
            }
            print("test")
        } label: {
            Label {
                Text("hello")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("HELLO")
                    }
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
            }
        }

Which triggers the print statement, but not the ShareLink.
I've also tried to use simultaneousGesture as well, but, no luck.
I do not want to use UIKit for my solution, I'd like to keep this a SwiftUI implementation.
Any suggestions? :)

There is no way you can catch when trigger ShareLink inside Menu. The only way to handle this is UIActivityViewController with Representable. :(
Apple says:

People tap or click on a share link to present a share interface. The
link typically uses a system-standard appearance; you only need to
supply the content to share


Yeah... I think this is sadly the answer. I ended up using those (UIActivityViewController and Representable). I was just really hoping that someone had a better understanding and could maybe reverse engineer it better than me!
Maybe someone else will find it and update later, but for now, this is the solution I've gone with.
Also thank you!

I agree with blackhatsrak above. If you and others are still looking for a UIKit solution, here it is:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu("options") {
                Button {
                    print("button 1 is pressed")
                } label: {
                    Text("Test Menu Button")
                }

                customShareLinkButton
            }
        }
    }

    var customShareLinkButton: some View {
        Button {
            presentShareLink()
        } label: {
            Label("share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
    }
    
    func presentShareLink() {
        print("your logic here")
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/") else { return }
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
        let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive } as? UIWindowScene
        scene?.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

You can replace the print statement in the presentShareLink function with your own logic. Although it looks a bit verbose, it still does the job to present the share link sheet.

There is a simpler solution than the ones that have been proposed.
To solve this, you can use the simultaneousGesture modifier, which allows you to have multiple gestures with the same priority.
ShareLink(item: url) {
    MenuButton(imageName: .iconShare)
        .disabled(true)
}
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture()
    .onEnded { _ in
        print("tapped")
})

